# My function always returns a boolean value instead of query results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an application that reads in one of its classes:

```
public function __construct()
{
  global $config;
  //Establish a connection to the database and get results set
  $this->db = new Database("localhost",$config["dbuser"],$config["dbpass"],"student");
  $this->records = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM major") or die("ERROR: ".$this->db->error);
  echo "<pre>".var_dump($this->records)."</pre>";
}
```

My problem is that `var_dump shows` that `$this->records` is a boolean. I've read the documentation and see that the SELECT query should return a result set.  This is the only query used by the application.

The DB Class:

```
  class Database
  {
      private $con;

     public function __construct($server,$user,$password,$database)
     {
        $this->con = new mysqli($server,$user,$password,$database) or die ("FATAL ERR: ".mysqli_error());
     }

    public function query($qry)
   {
     if(!isset($this->con)) die("ERROR: YOU ARE TRYING TO QUERY BEFORE THE CONNECTION IS ESTABLISHED!");
     return $this->con->query($qry) or die("FATAL ERROR:".$this->con->error);
   }
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, does the question/bounty here still relevant? I'm not so sure what exactly the problem is. Can you please clarify?

Comment: In case the query is not a `select` query (update/insert for example) the result of the `mysqli::query` will **not** be a result_set, but a boolean. Perhaps this what was unclear here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is incorrect. The assignment operator (`=`) has a higher precedence than the literal "or" operator. (Not to be confused with the "`||`" operator, which has a higher precedence than "`=`".)

There seems to be a bug in `mysqli::query()`, that causes it to return the boolean "true" in rare cases on a select statement. (Legal return values would be the boolean "false" or a `mysqli_result` object.)

You don't have to believe me on that assertion, you can easily try it yourself in a PHP shell:

```
$a = false or true;
var_dump($a);
```

Result:

```
bool (false)
```

That is because the above assignment is equivalent to:

```
($a = false) or true;
```

Comment: there is no assignment operator in question

Comment: As a matter of fact there is: $this->records = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM major") or die("ERROR: ".$this->db->error);

Comment: his problem is earlier in the code. the function in question is not `Database::query` which you are referring to but `mysqli::query` which is called withing the former.  `return $this->con->query($qry) or die()` is the problem statement

Comment: I don't see the problem with that... if the "or die(...)" is evaluated the script will terminate and the method won't return anything at all.

Comment: Indeed it was me who is blind. but still, there are no bugs in mysqli. so most likely the code in the OP is not a real one.

Comment: The thing is that I stumbled over this question because I seem to be having the same problem. MySQLi::query returned true on a SELECT statement and on the next query after that I got a "the mysql server has gone away".

Comment: That would be difficult, as it gives away internals of my company. However, I think that answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218775/mysqliquery-returns-true-on-select-queries --- the script forks and runs four instances simultaneously, so race conditions might very well be a problem.

Comment: erm... Having thought about it you have been correct after all. The expression (25 or die) returns the boolean "true", not 25. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this question is not related to `mysqli_query()` function, but to the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php).

There, the `=` operator has a *higher* precedence over `OR` operator, means assignment will be executed before `OR` (I explained this behavior in detail in the other answer, [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die/15320411#15320411) )

The problem line is

```
 return $this->con->query($qry) or die("FATAL ERROR:".$this->con->error);
```

Here, `return` operator has (for the obvious reason) the lowest precedence possible. Means that first PHP will execute the logical operator and then return its result - a boolean value!

But why doesn't the script actually die due to the logical operator execution?

Because of that logical operator execution optimization explained in the answer by the link above. *PHP doesn't bother to actually execute the rightmost operator.* It's enough that the leftmost one is already evaluates to `true`, means the whole expression will return `true` either way.

To solve this problem, the code of the function have to be changed this way:

```
public function query($qry)
{
    $ret = $this->con->query($qry) or trigger_error($this->con->error);
    return $ret;
}
```

while the calling code should be changed to simple

```
$this->records = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM major");
echo "<pre>".var_dump($this->records)."</pre>";
```

call, as checking for the error for the second time makes no sense - this function will never return a `false`-like value.

Answer (score -1):

The answer would be in what is called Magic Methods. One of PHP's magic methods is called __debugInfo(). If this Magic Method is defined, when you call var_dumb(obj), it will output whatever the function says to output. This is normally done to hide the private and protected functions of a parent class.